# Print asp panel on barcode sticker

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, panel, qr-code

I have a ASP panel with a barcode image(right side) and  Item information on the left side.

As i googled , i got to know as it can't be done from server side and hence i opt to do at client side as in the below code. But it let the user to choose the printer , which i don't want (as there are many printers connected to the system) . Is there any other  way to achieve it by defaulting the printer.

**Javascript Approach-**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function PrintPanel() {
        var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlContents.ClientID %>");
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            printWindow.print();
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }
    </script>
```

**Server Side Approach-**

```
 void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {         
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        using Font printFont=new Font("Arial",10.0f))
        {
            g.DrawImage(???)// How to convert my asp panel to image here?
        }
    }
```

***Or is there any other preferable way to do it??***

Comment: Put the image of the barcode inside the panel.

Comment: Image of barcode is already inside the panel.